# How to update time in DateTime() in access in increasing order with regular time interval?

Tags: ms-access

How to update time in DateTime() to access in an increasing order with regular time interval?

I want to update time with difference of 4 min, for particular set of records. for example time

```
03-06-2015 11:45:37 AM.
```

Now I want to update 20 records with time difference of 4 min i.e.

```
03-06-2015 11:45:37 AM, 
03-06-2015 11:49:37 AM, 
03-06-2015 11:53:37 AM, 
03-06-2015 11:57:37 AM, 
03-06-2015 12:01:37 PM, 
03-06-2015 12:05:37 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a recordset holding the 20 records and read time (StartTime) from the first record.

Then loop through the recordset doing an Edit and Update for each record where you set:

```
rs.Edit
    StartTime = DateAdd("n", 4, StartTime)
    rs!YourTimeField.Value = StartTime
rs.Update
rs.MoveNext
```

A query can look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    10 * Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) + Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) AS Id, 
    DateAdd("n",[Id] * 4, [StartTime]) AS NextTime
FROM 
    msysobjects AS Uno, 
    msysobjects AS Deca
WHERE 
    (10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) + Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10)) < 20;
```

Result:

```
Id  NextTime
0   03-06-2015 11:45:37
1   03-06-2015 11:49:37
2   03-06-2015 11:53:37
3   03-06-2015 11:57:37
4   03-06-2015 12:01:37
5   03-06-2015 12:05:37
6   03-06-2015 12:09:37
7   03-06-2015 12:13:37
8   03-06-2015 12:17:37
9   03-06-2015 12:21:37
10  03-06-2015 12:25:37
11  03-06-2015 12:29:37
12  03-06-2015 12:33:37
13  03-06-2015 12:37:37
14  03-06-2015 12:41:37
15  03-06-2015 12:45:37
16  03-06-2015 12:49:37
17  03-06-2015 12:53:37
18  03-06-2015 12:57:37
19  03-06-2015 13:01:37
```

Comment: @ Gustav:  it does not work. I try to create query but it is giving some error.

ERROR is : You havw written a Subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query' FROM caluse. Revise the Select statement of the subquery to request only one field.

QUERY

UPDATE Forms SET Forms.LastUpdateDT = (SELECT Forms.ID, Forms.CreatedDT, Forms.LastUpdateDT 

FROM Forms 

WHERE (((Forms.CreatedDT)>=[Start Date] And (Forms.CreatedDT)<=[End Date])))

WHERE (((Forms.LastUpdateDT)>=[Start Date] And (Forms.LastUpdateDT)<=[End Date]));

Comment: It does work, but it is neither a subquery nor SQL but the part of the VBA code inside the loop to perform the task. If you insist, you can use SQL for this but that will be quite clumsy and way slower.

Comment: @ Gustav: No issue i l want use SQL for this. that will be very much helpful. My client want SQL query not VBA or subquery.

Comment: OK, query added to answer.

Comment: Thanks I let you know

Comment: @ Gustav:  Thanks it is working great ... One last thing i want to know. In result it taking ID from 0 to 19. May I give range like record number 100 to 145 and it update from user defined record number?

Comment: Yes, just _add_ 100 to the expression for _Id_. And then _subtract_ 100 from Id when used in _DateAdd_.

Comment: @ Gustav:  I am trying to implement the query & logic in my table but I cannot.
the fields are ID and CreatDT. 
here i am trying to give user defined record number "ID" & "creatid" and datetime in Field "creatID" gets Update.

Comment: You may have to reveal your logic.

Comment: UPDATE Forms SET [Forms].[CreatDT] = 10*Abs([Forms].[ID] Mod 10)+Abs([Forms].[ID] Mod 10) WHERE (((Forms.ID)=Forms.ID) And (Forms.ID=Forms.CreatDT)) = [Forms].[ID];

Comment: This has no relation to my query, so it won't generate any date/times. You will have to somehow select the 20 records to be updated, then create an update query that pulls the date/times from my query. Still, I'm convinced this would be much easier and faster to carry out in a simple loop in VBA as to my original suggestion.

Comment: @ Gustav: I am have no doubt that your VBA query will not work but my client wants SQL query only.

what i understand from your suggestion is that first i run select query and fetch records, then I run your code. it means i need to run Nested query. Am I Right?

Comment: Yes, somehow you will have join your table with my query.

Comment: @ Gustav: This is the query I have created.
SELECT Forms.ID, Forms.CreatedDT FROM Forms
Where Forms.ID >=[Start] AND Forms.ID<=[END];
UPDATE Forms SET Forms.CreatDT = (SELECT Forms.ID, Forms.CreatDT FROM Forms Where Forms.ID >=[Start] AND Forms.ID<=[END])
where (Select 10 * Abs([Forms].[ID] Mod 10) + Abs([Forms].[CreatDT] Mod 10), DateAdd("n",[Formd.CreatedID] * 4, [StartTime]) 
FROM Forms WHERE (10*Abs([Forms].[ID] Mod 10) + Abs([Forms].[ID] Mod 10)) < 20);

Comment: @ Gustav: 
As you said this Query SELECT Forms.ID, Forms.CreatedDT FROM Forms Where Forms.ID >=[Start] AND Forms.ID<=[END] will fetch the records from the range I provide.
Because I am applying it into a single table I remove DISTINCT, Uno, Decca and in place of Uno & Decca I gave my table name Forms.Now tell me what and where I am doing wrong. Its not working

Comment: I don't think you can because the SQL for the date generating is not updatable. So you may have to write the result from the date query to a temp table, then use this table to update your Forms table with a normal update query.

Comment: @ Gustav:  This is the query i made. 

UPDATE Forms SET [Forms].[CreatDT]=DateAdd("n",CreatID*4,[CreatID])  where ([Forms.ID] = [Start] AND [Forms.ID] = [END]);

it is giving error Data Type Miss match.
Please help to resolve

Comment: You must use a date value, probably: _DateAdd("n",CreatedID*4,[CreatedDT])_

Comment: @ Gustav:    
UPDATE Forms SET [Forms].[CreatedDT]=DateAdd("n",[CreatedDT]*4,[StartTime])  where ([Forms].[ID] = [Start] AND [Forms].[ID] = [END]);

Query Executed but message given ZERO RECORDS Updated

Comment: Hard to guess. Check the Start and End values.

Comment: @ Gustav:  I made correction in query.
Query i executing but not giving desired out put. It is updating the records but.. When in StartTime I give: 02-05-2016 09:49:03 AM, Output =  28-08-2016 10:38:03 AM in all 50 records. Where as it should be 02-05-2016 09:49:03 AM, 02-05-2016 09:53:03 AM, 02-05-2016 09:57:03 AM & so on for 50 records.

The query is: 
UPDATE Forms SET [Forms].[CreatedDT]=DateAdd("n",[CreatedDT]*4,[StartTime]) where ([Forms].[ID] >= [Start] AND [Forms].[ID] <= [END]);

Kindly tell what and where is wrong.

Comment: Try with _DateAdd("n",[CreatedID]*4,[StartTime])_

Comment: @ Gustav: Error: Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression

Comment: _Start_ and _End_ must match _Forms!ID_

Comment: @ Gustav: Start and End are Ok. Because they define range of record or ID to be modified.

Comment: Then it must be the Forms!ID values to check.